# What happens when bounty user and OP are different?

Tags: discussion, questions, bounties

I am talking about this question

[Catch error if iframe src fails to load . Error :-"Refused to display 'http://www.google.co.in/' in a frame.."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273042/catch-error-if-iframe-src-fails-to-load-error-refused-to-display-http-ww)

In this question OP is user "SDG - Shubh Dasgupta"  but user "Varun Vohra" has opened bounty.

My question is for information only who is going to accept the answer .. I think it should be OP only but since Varun has spent 100 reputation points he might be able to accept the answer.

What happens in this kind of situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The accepted answer is exclusively determined by the person that asked the question.  They can mark an answer, unmark an answer, or change the marked answer, at any time.

The person that has a bounty will, separately, choose who gets the bounty at the end of it's period.

Answer (score 4):

The OP can accept an answer, and the bounty owner can decide where the bounty will be awarded. The two are totally independent.